# Can Spring JPA matched multiple records for List

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a class called product which has lots of tags.

Such object define as below:

```
public class Product{
    @ManyToMany
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Tag> tags;
}
```

Since a product may has lots of tags. If I want to select a product with tags A and B at the same time. Could I implement it in JPA way?

I can do it easily with native query`SELECT t.product_id FROM ta_product p INNER JOIN ta_product_tags t ON p.id = t.product_id GROUP BY t.product_id HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t.tags_id IN (?1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= ?2 LIMIT ?3,?4` But it do not support `Pageable` interface.

I try to write a Query like these

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT(p.id) FROM Product p INNER JOIN p.tags t WHERE SUM(CASE WHEN t.id IN ?1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= ?2 ")
int countByTags(List<Long> tagIds, long length);
```

It told me that `Invalid use of group function`

Any solution that I can make use of `Pageable` interface?

Comment: "It told me" : what is "it", and why not post the complete exception + stack trace? Also no idea what "SUM" is doing there

Comment: @DN1 "it" means the spring jpa. I do some research but no ideas how to make "correct" usage of it. Use SUM to make sure that No. of Tags match the tags input.

Comment: So Post The exception and we can see what is throwing it

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution by myself

```
@Query("SELECT COUNT (p1.id) FROM Product p1 WHERE p1.deleted = false AND EXISTS (SELECT p FROM Product p INNER JOIN p.tags t WHERE p1.id = p.id GROUP BY p.id HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t.id IN ?1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= ?2)")
int countByTags(List<Long> tagIds, long length);
```